# How to disable logging images in nginx but still allow the get request?

Tags: http, nginx, access-log

I'm trying to log only java-script files request in the nginx access_log.
I tried using the following code i found on this site:

```
location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|html|htm|ico|xml|svg)$ {
   access_log        off;
}
```

the problem is it doesn't allow the get request at all and i get a 404 error when trying to run the html file that executes the js file in the browse.

I want everything to work just the same but for the access log to log only request for js files.
How do i do that?

Answer (score 15):

Put it in the server block and make sure that the "root" is correctly set up. It does work

Working example:

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires    +60d;
    access_log off;
}
```

I have this in the server block and not a location block.

Comment: i did as you suggested:
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  X.XXX.XXX.XX;

       

        location / {
            root   html/run;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
 location ~* \.(css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|html)$ {
     
              access_log   off;
    
       }
}

but it prevents access to the files all together.
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Did you mean leaving it empty like that:
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ { }
?
It didn't work this way.
the pages were not loaded (404)

Comment: No,  just take it away completely. Just trying to figure out where the problem is.   Can you view images if you take it away and reload nginx.

Comment: Yes i can. it was the original set up

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can keep all requests within single `location` but use `access_log` with condidional `if` operator to disable images logging:

```
map $request_uri $is_loggable {
    ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|html|htm|ico|xml|svg)$ 0;
    default                                             1;
}
server {
    location / {
        access_log /path/to/log/file combined if=$is_loggable;
        ...
    }
}
```

Here `combined` is a name of default log format.

You say that you want to log only java-script files, so actually you can use even simplier solution:

```
map $request_uri $is_loggable {
    ~* ^.+\.js$  1;
    default      0;
}
```

Comment: didnt work for me, nginx syntax error : nginx: [emerg] invalid number of the map parameters

Comment: Just need to adjust the map by quoting the first parameter:

`map $request_uri $is_loggable {
  default                                               1;
  '~*^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|html|htm|ico|xml|svg|js|map|woff|woff2)$' 0;
}`